# Como atualizar o pivot no LARAVEL 4 usando o método UPDATE?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, modelo-relacional, relacionamento

Eu tenho dois Models que são ligados, através do `belongsToMany`, a uma tabela de relacionamento N:N.

De sorte que a estrutura está disposta da seguinte forma:

[image: Diagrama EER]

```
class Permissao extends Eloquent{
   public function niveis()
   {
       return $this->belongsToMany('Nivel', 'niveis_permissoes');
   }
}


class Nivel extends Permissao
{
   public function permissoes()
   {
         return $this->belongsToMany('Permissao', 'niveis_permissoes')
                     ->withPivot('prioridade');
   }
}
```

Nesse cenário, preciso atualizar o campo "prioridade" que está na tabela niveis_permissoes, de acordo com o `nivel_id` e `permissao_id` informados.

Eu consegui fazer a atualização dos dados, trazendo primeiro o resultado e, depois, usando o método `save`, de `pivot`.

```
$pivot = Nivel::findOrFail($nivelID)
                ->permissoes()
                ->whereId($permissaoID)
                ->first()->pivot;

$pivot->fill(['prioridade' => $prioridade])->save();
```

Porém, eu não quero trazer esses dados, mas quero simplesmente atualizá-los diretamente através do objeto retornado quando construímos a query pelo `Eloquent`(que é a classe `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`), como geralmente se faz numa operação de somente atualização de dados.

Veja:

```
$isUpdated = Permissao::where('url', 'like', 'usuario%')
                   ->update(['status' =>` 0]);
```

Mesmo já funcionado primeiro exemplo de atualização (via método `save`), como poderia utilizar o método `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::update()` para atualizar um campo dessa table `niveis_permissoes`, da mesma forma que fiz com o `save`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Galera, acabei descobrindo, ao "navegar" pelo código fonte da classe `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany`.

Lá, existe um método chamado `updateExistingPivot`.

Exemplo:

```
Nivel::findOrFail($nivelID)
->permissoes()
->updateExistingPivot($permissaoID, ['prioridade' => 5]);
```

Comment: Não entendi de onde veio o permissaoID, é um padrão do Eloquent ?